# Как добавить на сайт информер погоды текущего местоположения пользователя?

Tags: php, json, геолокация, weather

Хочу добавить на сайт простейший информер погоды текущего местоположения. Для этого в качестве кросс-доменного api взял [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/), зарегистрировался в бесплатном аккаунте и получил `api ключ`, получаю [такой json ответ](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=87d72aa1be3b31146eab1efa041ff764) при конкретном задании города (Лондон).

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk
```

А как задавать погоду для текущего положения пользователя, к примеру если он в Буркина-Фасо и об этом известно только его браузеру?

Comment: еще сервис для примера - https://sypexgeo.net/ru/api/

Comment: @Ilya Yaremchuk спасибо, но запрос
`$is_bot = preg_match(
 "~(Google|Yahoo|Rambler|Bot|Yandex|Spider|Snoopy|Crawler|Finder|Mail|curl)~i", 
 $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);
$geo = !$is_bot ? json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/'), true) : [];
var_dump($geo);`
неправильно определил мой api, страну и город и к сожалению, нет сервера для моей страны, поэто не он мне не подходит

Comment: Так есть целая статья посвященная как можно применять openweathermap [Тыц] Главное чтобы он по стилю хорошо вписывался на сайт. [Тыц]: https://active-vision.ru/blog/api-openweathermap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользоватся сервисом который по IP находит город, тоже не 100% точность, но думаю в большинстве случаев укажет верный город.

```
// Функция используется чисто чтобы определить IP.
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

$ip = get_client_ip();
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$ip"));
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryCode"];
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
```

В переменных те параметры что вам нужны, город и код страны.

Comment: спасибо! Но, не совсем в таком виде работает - не получает мой город `$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];`, хотя это мегаполис и столица и захожу с самого центра города, поэтому получаю инфу через координаты и поиск ближайшего к нему региона
`$latitude = $geo["geoplugin_latitude"];
$longitude = $geo["geoplugin_longitude"];
$string = "http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat=".$latitude."&long=".$longitude;
$place = unserialize(file_get_contents($string));
if($place["geoplugin_region"]) {
$city = $place["geoplugin_region"];
}
else {
 $city = "Your City";
}`

Comment: @Вася От базы IP зависит, проверял на своем городе и всё нормально

Comment: ок, понял, но надежнее все же похоже брать ближаешую точку относительно ширины-долготы

Comment: @Вася ну если сервис погоды сам может по координатам найти город то да

Comment: А можно по человечески ответить, а то все такие умные я смотрю! куда вставлять это всё?